# Menu Icons + Omega

Tags: routes, theming

I'm using [Menu Icons](http://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) with Omega and, well, my menu icons are cut off above and below the line. I've done all the CSS stuff I can think of and nothing seems to help. When I look at the documentation for Menu Icons, it looks like the icons are supposed to display at whatever height the image style is set to. I've checked both Firefox and Safari.

What could be causing this? How can Menu Icons be made to display the proper height?

I sort of managed to get the HTML/CSS into CSSdeck: http://cssdesk.com/rTRyh (ignore the stuff that isn't the menu with the icons).

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url("http://softpixel.com/~bbinkovitz/sites/default/files/public/twitter.png");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-spacing: 0px 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(90, 47, 158);
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
content: none;
counter-increment: none;
counter-reset: none;
cursor: pointer;
direction: ltr;
display: inline;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 400;
height: auto;
image-rendering: auto;
ime-mode: auto;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: 19.5px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-offset: auto;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
opacity: 1;
outline-color: rgb(90, 47, 158);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow: visible;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
resize: none;
right: auto;
shape-rendering: auto;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1px;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: left;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: -99999px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
width: auto;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
z-index: auto;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-direction: normal;
-moz-animation-duration: 0s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: none;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-name: none;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-backface-visibility: visible;
-moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;
-moz-binding: none;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-image: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
-moz-box-align: stretch;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-flex: 0;
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-pack: start;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-column-count: auto;
-moz-column-gap: 13px;
-moz-column-rule-color: rgb(90, 47, 158);
-moz-column-rule-style: none;
-moz-column-rule-width: 0px;
-moz-column-width: auto;
-moz-float-edge: content-box;
-moz-font-feature-settings: normal;
-moz-font-language-override: normal;
-moz-force-broken-image-icon: 0;
-moz-hyphens: manual;
-moz-image-region: auto;
-moz-orient: horizontal;
-moz-outline-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
-moz-outline-radius-bottomright: 0px;
-moz-outline-radius-topleft: 0px;
-moz-outline-radius-topright: 0px;
-moz-perspective: none;
-moz-perspective-origin: 31.6833px 9.5px;
-moz-stack-sizing: stretch-to-fit;
-moz-tab-size: 8;
-moz-text-align-last: auto;
-moz-text-blink: none;
-moz-text-decoration-color: rgb(90, 47, 158);
-moz-text-decoration-line: none;
-moz-text-decoration-style: solid;
-moz-text-size-adjust: auto;
-moz-transform: none;
-moz-transform-origin: 31.6833px 9.5px;
-moz-transform-style: flat;
-moz-transition-delay: 0s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0s;
-moz-transition-property: all;
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
-moz-user-focus: none;
-moz-user-input: auto;
-moz-user-modify: read-only;
-moz-user-select: auto;
-moz-window-shadow:   default;
```

I'm still curious about this as a Drupal-specific issue, since it seems like some conflict between Omega's and Menu Icons' styles, or something.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue, have you tried using Firebug to get a better idea as to what is going on? It may be an idea to isolate it in something like [jsbin.com][1]. That would also allow us to take a look at the specific code and offer more help.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll be more specific. "I've done all the CSS stuff I can think of" means that I've inspected the element and tried to alter the height of the element and all of its parent elements.

Comment: As I've suggested above, it's probably a good idea to pull the related HTML (probably the `UL` and it's children), along with the CSS applied to each element (should be simple enough with Firebug) into [JSbin](http://jsbin.com) or similar.

Comment: May you provide a screenshot? Relying on an external site is usually a not good idea, for the fact that the question must be useful to future readers too. If the link gets broken, future readers will not see the CSS style applied, and not understand the given answers, nor if the question could apply to them too.